# Can't pull the source code of apache ignite 2.6 from github

Tags: git, github, version-control, ignite

When I pulled the source code of Apache ignite v2.6 on tag 2.6.0 from github.

```
macgaffin-mba:ignite macgaffin$ git checkout -b my-2.6.0 2.6.0
Switched to a new branch 'my-2.6.0'

macgaffin-mba:ignite macgaffin$ git log
commit 5faffcee7cfaae90d3093e624d27f1b69554ea10 (HEAD -> my-2.6.0, tag: 2.6.0, 
origin/ignite-2.6)
Author: Andrey Gura <agura@apache.org>
Date:   Mon Jul 9 18:10:45 2018 +0300

Release version fixed in release notes
```

I got the code with commit id 5faffcee7cfaae90d3093e624d27f1b69554ea10.
But actually, from the https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/2.6.0, we knew that the commit id on tag 2.6.0 is  669feac......

How can I get the code of tag 2.6.0?

Comment: what about `git checkout 2.6.0`?

Comment: @Xu Macgaffin Tim, Since this issue has been resolved, would you please mark the helpful reply as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

```
(HEAD -> my-2.6.0, tag: 2.6.0, origin/ignite-2.6)
```

That means your local tag refers to [origin/ignite-2.6](https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/ignite-2.6)

Try instead:

```
git tag -d 2.6.0
git fetch --tags
```

And then checkout again.